# LINQpad: Global function SubmitChanges not found

Tags: linqpad

I've got a C#-Statement in LINQpad 4.0 like this:

```
var x = (from y in MyTable
where y.ID == 12345
select y).Single(); 
x.PropA = "abc";
SubmitChanges();
```

When i execute the Statements i get the error
The name "SubmitChanges" is not available in the current context

How can i fix the problem or update my data using linqpad? 
On my research i just found something about using a second datacontext, but it should work with the first context...

Comment: I think you have to create your own context if you want to use methods like SubmitChanges

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you've not set a database (connection). Choose a database from the dropdown list above the query, or drag a connection from the Schema Explorer on the left onto your query.

Answer (score 0):

For the Entity Framework, you'll need to use the method `SaveChanges()` [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges(v=vs.113).aspx).