# LINQPad "The name SubmitChanges does not exist"

Tags: virtual-machine, linqpad, submitchanges

Working with LINQPad 5 on virtual machine win 10. Select queries work, now I try to use update query and it gives me an error about SubmitChanges() method.

> CS0103 The name 'SubmitChanges' does not exist in the current context.

Basically all answers that I found are like this: write SubmitChanges() or SaveChanges()  if you are using EF. Also I tried to change from C# Statements to C# Program.

[How to submit changes in LinqPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438924/how-to-submit-changes-in-linqpad)

In one answer user might not add a connection, which I did. (screen 1)
[LINQpad: Global function SubmitChanges not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388318/linqpad-global-function-submitchanges-not-found)

Then I tried to pass a "this" to a method, and in my case "this" is an UserQuery, not a DataContext. (screen 2) Which is wierd.

[linqpad - SubmitChanges Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355686/linqpad-submitchanges-extension)

```
void Main()
{
var ret =from t in Tbblankimages where t.Comment == "1234" select     t;    
var im = ret.First();   
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using (FileStream file = new     FileStream("E:\\saved.jpg",FileMode.Open,System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
{
file.CopyTo(ms);
}
byte[] imageData= ms.ToArray();
im.Image = imageData;   
Test(this);
}
static void Test(System.Data.Linq.DataContext c)
{
 c.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Screenshots with error messages:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqJ1Z.jpg   (screen 1)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogcbi.jpg   (screen 2)

Also I should add that the database is PostgreSQL and I use custom driver to it from here:
https://github.com/fknx/linqpad-postgresql-driver
Version of Postgresql is 11.3-4-windows-x64

Answer (score 3):

With postgresql driver it works differently:

https://github.com/fknx/linqpad-postgresql-driver

```
   var user = Users.Single(u => u.Id == 42);

   user.Emailaddress = "john.doe@abc.com";

   this.Update(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Linqpad disconnects and causes this problem.
I click on the top left `Refresh` button to solve this problem.
[image: 20190624152912.png]